# RecyclerView with different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

when i use this

```
@Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
  }
```

my RecyclerView  work without problem
now i want to use multi layout on it i use this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   int type = -1;
   if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("left"))         type = 1;
   else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("right"))   type = 0;
   else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("typing"))  type = 2;
   return type;
  //return position;

}
```

the problem when i used it's and scroll to top and back to bottom or just scrolling
its reorder item in `RecyclerView` like make the first item on it the last one or on middle or every where not i the correct position

> just if i back to the first code of `getItemViewType` its work without
>   problem  but i cant use multi layout

my full code

```
 public class MessageAdapter1 extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter1.ViewHolder> {

private List<MessageList> mMessages;
private int[] mUsernameColors;
private Context context;


public MessageAdapter1(Context context, List<MessageList> messages) {  
    mMessages = messages;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layout = -1;



    switch (viewType) {
    case 0:
        layout = R.layout.right_message;
        break;
    case 1:
        layout = R.layout.left_message;
        break;
    case 2:
        layout = R.layout.message_left;
        break;
    }



    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout , parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    MessageList message = mMessages.get(position);


    //viewHolder.setMessage(message.getMessage());
    //viewHolder.setUsername(message.getUsername());
    viewHolder.setGroupMessage(message);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessages.size();
}



@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int type = -1;
    if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("left"))         type = 1;
    else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("right"))   type = 0;
    else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("typing"))  type = 2;
    return type;
    //return position;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private LinearLayout groupMessage;
    //private ImageView   typing;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        groupMessage = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.messages);

    }

    public void setGroupMessage(MessageList m) {


        if (null == groupMessage) return;

        int i = 0;

        if(m.getMessageStatus() == false){
          m.setMessageStatus(true);
            for (String message : m.getMessageList()) {

                //TextView text = new TextView(activity);
                TextView text = new MyTextView(context);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                p.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 2);

                if (m.getDir().equals("left")) {

                    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                    if(m.getMessageList().size() == 1){
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left_default);
                    }
                    else if (i == 0) {
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left_first);
                    } else if (i + 1 == m.getMessageList().size()) {
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left_last);
                    } else {
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left);
                    }


                } else{

                    p.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    if(m.getMessageList().size() == 1){
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right_default);
                    }
                    else if (i == 0) {
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right_first);
                    } else if (i + 1 == m.getMessageList().size()) {
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right_last);
                    } else {
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right);
                    }

                }


                text.setLayoutParams(p);
                text.setText(message);
                text.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

                text.setTextSize(18f);



                //text.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
                groupMessage.addView(text);
                i++;
            }

        }




    }



  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by remove

```
int type = -1;
if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("left"))         type = 1;
else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("right"))   type = 0;
else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("typing"))  type = 2;
return type;
```

from

```
getItemViewType
```

and return `position`

and put the first code

```
 int type = -1;
if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("left"))         type = 1;
else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("right"))   type = 0;
else if(mMessages.get(position).getDir().equals("typing"))  type = 2;
return type;
```

in onCreateViewHolder and use `viewType` as the current position